# c# how to look in a child window for a button and click on it programatically

Tags: c#

I would like to know how can i activate a button programatically with the help of user32 dll. Thx for helping.

In the next code i get handle over my specific window. Now I would like to activate a button that this window has (the Open button).

**Is there a way I can search and print everything that the handler sees in the window (the button open, close...and so on)?**

Need help!!

Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder(256);
  StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(256);
        GetWindowText(hwnd, bld, 256);
        GetClassName(hwnd, className, 256);  
        string text = bld.ToString();
        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pointer: " + hwnd.ToInt32().ToString() + " Window Title: " + text);
            if (text == "my_window") { 
                Console.WriteLine(bld.ToString()+"..."+className.ToString()+"..."+hwnd.ToString());

                System.IntPtr ptrChild = GetWindow(hwnd,5);
                IntPtr handll = FindWindow(className.ToString(), "my_window");
                if (handll == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not working");
                }
                SetForegroundWindow(handll);

               while (!handll.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)){ //HOW TO CHECK (FIND) FOR THE OK BUTTON?!}
..}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for all controls using [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindowEx(parentWindow, IntPtr.Zero, null, null);
while(handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    GetWindowText(handle, bld, 255);
    MessageBox.Show(bld.ToString()); // writes out displayed text
    handle = FindWindowEx(parentWindow, handle, null, null);
}
```

Optionally, you can search only buttons:

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindowEx(parentWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "BUTTON", null);
while(handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    GetWindowText(handle, bld, 255);
    MessageBox.Show(bld.ToString()); // writes out displayed text
    handle = FindWindowEx(parentWindow, handle, "BUTTON", null);
}
```

Comment: where should i put the button search? Inside  while (!handll.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)){ ? thx.please help.

Comment: My FindWindowEx needs an intptr instead of "Button". How could i change it?

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className,  IntPtr windowTitle);

Comment: ok,thx i did change iti added :   if (ptrChild == FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "BUTTON", "Save as")) {   SendMessage(ptrChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                          SendMessage(ptrChild, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                          SendMessage(ptrChild, 0, 1, IntPtr.Zero);} BUT I DON'T SEE ANY RESULT. WHY?

Comment: SendMessage(WM_CLICK) would be enough. I don't know? Does FindWindowEx find any button?

Comment: BTW, this would work only if the application is written using winforms (spy++ can help you identifying which button to pick). QT, and other frameworks doesn't work this way.